# sacar array de strings de un array de objetos anidado

Tags: javascript, angular

estoy tratando de sacar un string conformado desde un array de objetos anidados de este tipo:

```
      {
        id: 'id1',
        nombre: 'nombre 1',
        roles: [
          { id: 'ROL1', nombre: 'rol 1' },
          { id: 'ROL2', nombre: 'rol 2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'id2',
        nombre: 'nombre 2',
        roles: [
          { id: 'ROL3', nombre: 'rol 3' },
          { id: 'ROL4', nombre: 'rol 4' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'id3',
        nombre: 'nombre 3',
        roles: [
          { id: 'ROL5', nombre: 'Rol 5' },
          { id: 'ROL6', nombre: 'Rol 6' },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

Lo que quiero sacar es lo siguiente:

```
nombre 1- rol 1 - rol 2, nombre 2 - rol 3 - rol 4, nombre 3 - rol 5 - rol 6
```

pero obtengo lo siguiente:

```
nombre 1 - rol 1,nombre 1 - rol 2,nombre 2 - rol 3,nombre 2 - rol 4,nombre 3 - Rol 5,nombre 3 - Rol 6
```

Aqui mi [stacklitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qqnyjf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando un `forEach` para el nombre y otro para los roles puedes realizarlo como se ve en el ejemplo:

```js
const log = document.querySelector('#log');
const data = [{
    id: 'id1',
    nombre: 'nombre 1',
    roles: [{
        id: 'ROL1',
        nombre: 'rol 1'
      },
      {
        id: 'ROL2',
        nombre: 'rol 2'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id2',
    nombre: 'nombre 2',
    roles: [{
        id: 'ROL3',
        nombre: 'rol 3'
      },
      {
        id: 'ROL4',
        nombre: 'rol 4'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id3',
    nombre: 'nombre 3',
    roles: [{
        id: 'ROL5',
        nombre: 'Rol 5'
      },
      {
        id: 'ROL6',
        nombre: 'Rol 6'
      },
    ],
  },
];
let result = '';

data.forEach((value, index) => {
  result += index > 0 ? ', ' + value.nombre : value.nombre;
  value.roles.forEach((rol) => (result += ` - ${rol.nombre}`));
});

log.textContent = result;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<main id="log"></main>
```